# Django with Sqlite: Q(...)&Q(...) is NOT the same as filter(...).filter(...)

Tags: django, sqlite

my models.py:

```
class Words(models.Model):

    sentence = models.ForeignKey(Sentences, related_name='sentence_having_this_word')
    wordtext = models.CharField( max_length=250) # NOT UNIQUE. words written similarly can appear, as long as the sentences are different.

class Sentences(BaseModel): 
    pass
```

Let´s say I have 2 sentences:
`I see a tree and a house.`  and `the tree is in front of the house.`

the `Words` contains : `'I'`, `'see'`, `'a'`, `'tree'`, `'and'`, `'a'`,  `'house'` (all these words with ForeignKey to the first sentence), `'the'`, `'tree'`, `'is'`, `'in'`, `'front'`, `'of'`, `'the'`, `'house'` (these words with FK to the second sentence).

I'm looking for the sentences which have these 2 words written similarly inside, `'tree'` and `'house'`.

I do:

`Sentences.objects.filter(Q(sentence_having_this_word__wordtext='tree')&Q(sentence_having_this_word__wordtext='house')).all()`

==> []. No result

but if I do:
 `Sentences.objects.filter(sentence_having_this_word__wordtext='tree').filter(sentence_having_this_word__wordtext='house')).all()`

==> I've got the expected result:
`I see a tree and a house.`, `the tree is in front of the house.`

I thought `Q(...)&Q(...)` and `filter(...).filter(...)` were the same thing?

**EDIT** The `&` Operator DOES NOT work!

With `and`, it's working...

in the docs, it's not mentioned (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is documented under ["Spanning multi-valued relationships"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

When a lookup spans a multi-valued relationship, such as a reverse foreign key in this case, filters inside a single `.filter()` call will filter for objects that have a single related object that satisfies both conditions. In this case, the `Sentence` must have a single related `Words` instance where `wordtext` equals both `'tree'` and `'house'`. Of course, this condition is never true.

When multiple `.filter()` calls are used, different objects may match the filters. In that case, a `Sentence` must have at least one related `Words` instance with `wordtext` equal to `'tree'`, and at least one (but possibly a different) `Words` instance with `wordtext` equal to `'house'`.

Your query with `and` does *not* work as expected. `and` is a logical operator that returns the last truthy value. A non-empty `Q` object is truthy, so:

```
Q(sentence_having_this_word__wordtext='tree') and Q(sentence_having_this_word__wordtext='house')
```

evaluates to:

```
Q(sentence_having_this_word__wordtext='house')
```

Since you have no sentences that contain `'house'`, but do not contain `'tree'`, the results are the same, but the query isn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot for having taken the time to write this. It's very clear now!